# Series expansion of $\arctan$ at arbitrary real point

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm looking for a closed form for the coefficients of the series expansion of $\arctan(x)$ at some real $x_0$. If $x_0 = 0$, the expansion is of course the well-known

$$\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\ .$$

In general, due to analyticity, the expansion is
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} \arctan^{(n)}(x_0) \cdot (x - x_0)^n = \\\arctan(x_0) + \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)_{\!|\, x=x_0}\! \cdot (x - x_0)^{n+1}$$

but I'm struggling to find a closed form for these coefficients
$$\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)_{\!|\, x=x_0}$$

In fact, I don't necessarily need a closed form as such; a recursive formula would also be all right.

UPDATE: Mathematica says the $n$-th coefficient in the series expansion of $\arctan(x)$ at $x = x_0$ is:
$$\frac{-i}{2}\left((-i-x_0)^{-(n+1)} - (i-x_0)^{-(n+1)}\right)$$
One can probably derive this using a partial fraction expansion like Daniel Fischer suggested in his comment and then the geometric series. But I'm struggling to simplify this result to a ‘purely real’ formula.

UPDATE: After some rewriting, I found the following formula:
$$\arctan(x) = \arctan(0) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n\arg(i-x_0))}{n(x_0^2+1)^{\frac{n}{2}}} (x - x_0)^n$$

I guess one can simplify the $\arg(i-x_0)$ using $\arctan$. Not sure if the result is the easiest form one can get though.

Comment: If you're not afraid of complex numbers, the partial fraction decomposition $$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{2i}\biggl(\frac{1}{x-i} - \frac{1}{x+i}\biggr)$$ helps finding a closed form for the derivatives.

Comment: Yes, Mathematica gave me something like that as well when I asked it for the coefficients, but I'd very much prefer a ‘purely real’ solution if possible.

Comment: Actually, I thought about it a bit more and I think I know what to do now. Thanks!

Comment: At second thought, no, I still get stuck.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/20/02/)?

Comment: I had not, thanks. But the second one is the solution I already have and the others are a bit too ugly for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the updates of my question, I did find some rather ugly closed-form solutions for the coefficients, but I wasn't very happy with them.

I then realised that, given the partial fraction decomposition pointed out by Daniel Fischer, I could simply find a linear recurrence equation for them:

$$\arctan(x) = \arctan(x_0) + \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{b_n}{n}(x-x_0)^n$$
$$\quad\text{where}\quad b_n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if}\ n = 0\\ \frac{1}{1+x_0^2} & \text{if}\ n = 1\\ -\frac{1}{1+x_0^2}\left(2x_0 b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}\right) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

That's pretty much exactly what I wanted – purely real and easy to compute. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: Can one confirm quickly just from this formula that the radius of convergence is what it should be according to complex analysis, namely, $\sqrt{1+x_0^2}$? I have played around with $\lvert \frac {b_{n-1}}{b_n} \rvert$ a little and did not get to the desired result.

Comment: What I gave above for $b_n$ is a linear homogeneous recurrence equation, which can easily be solved explicitly using e.g. Mathematica/WolframAlpha. The solution will have the form $b_n = a z^n + b \bar{z}^n$ where $a, b, z$ are complex numbers. But I fear reading off the limit of $b_{n+1}/b_n$ from that will be difficult...

Comment: Ah, but that is as good as it gets and does the job. Actually, those $z$ are $\dfrac{x_0 \pm i}{x_0^2+1}$ which do have absolute value $=(x_0^2+1)^{-1/2}$, and then it's a straightforward exercise (I used that $\pi$ is irrational though, to get real parts close to absolute values) that $\limsup_n \lvert az^n +b\bar z ^n \rvert^{1/n} = (x_0^2+1)^{-1/2}$. Indeed one should not look at those consecutive quotients $b_{n-1}/b_n$ at all, because they oscillate seemingly randomly, and are occasionally $0$ or undefined (the case $x_0=1$ is quite telling though, there's a nice period of $4$ coming up).

Comment: Very nice! I did not think of using the $n$-th root form of the convergence radius with the lim sup.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the $n$th derivative of $\arctan z$ is
\begin{equation*}
(\arctan z)^{(n)}
=\frac{(n-1)!}{(2z)^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac{(2z)^{2k}}{(1+z^2)^{k+1}}.
\end{equation*}
Using this result, one can write out Taylor's series expansion of arctan at arbitrary real point. This result can be found in the following paper:

1. Feng Qi and Mark Daniel Ward, *Closed-form formulas and properties of coefficients in Maclaurin's series expansion of Wilf's function*, arXiv (2021), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08576v1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this series expansion of the arctangent function:

$\arctan(x) = \frac{i}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} \left( \frac{1}{(i + x)^n} - \frac{1}{( i - x)^n}\right)$

may also be useful. See this [paper](https://doi.org/10.3390/appliedmath3020020) for derivation.